# Consumir API Rest em Delphi

Tags: delphi, rest

Estou tentando consumir API Rest, feita em php, a partir de uma aplicação Delphi. Em resumo a API recebe um campo chamado nome, outro campo são as partes partes, mas nesse caso o campo é um arry de partes com a seguinte estrutura: partes[]['email'], partes[]['funcao'], na sequencia um campo rejeitavel do tipo boolean e por fim o arquivo que vai ser sempre um pdf.
Segue o código:

```
var
  params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  ss: TStringStream;
   arq : TMemoryStream;
   IdHTTP : TIdHTTP;
   email, funcao : array of String;
begin

  params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  email := ['enderecodeemail@gmail.com'];
  funcao := ['assinar'];
  ss := TStringStream.Create('');
  params.AddFormField('nome', 'Contrato aluno');
  params.AddFormField('partes[]', email[0]);
  params.AddFormField('parte[]', funcao[0]);
  params.AddFormField('rejeitavel', 'false');
  params.AddFile('Contrato','C:\arquivos\Contrato.pdf', 'application/pdf');
 // params.AddFormField('nome', 'Pasta Teste');

  Try
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IdHTTP.Request.Clear;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----BOUNDARY';
    IdHTTP.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Autntiq-Api', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Post('https://api.xxxx.com.br/documentos.json', params,ss);      
  end;

end;
```

quando executo ele retorna o erro:

Project xxxxxxxxx raised exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity'.

O codigo de resposta HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity indica que o servidor entende o tipo de conteúdo da entidade da requisição, e a sintaxe da requisição esta correta, mas não foi possível processar as instruções presentes.

Testei com outro método da API e tive sucesso. Não consigo identificar se o problema está no camo partes[] como array ou no envio do arquivo.

Agradeço pela ajuda e Glorifico a Deus pela vida de todos!!!!

Comment: (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity significa que o servidor entendeu o conteúdo e sintaxe da requisição, mas foi incapaz de processar as instruções. Resumo: parece que o erro esta no código PHP.